# Android kotlin set SharingStarted property of MutableSharedFlow without "shareIn" operator

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

My particular implementation concerns the use of kotlin flows in Android, but I guess this is applicable to kotlin in general.

What I would like to do is to set my `SharedFlow` to be started according to the [`SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-sharing-started/-while-subscribed.html) started policy, so that the flow materializes only when the number of subscribers is greater than zero.

The recommended way to setup such a flow from the [android official guide](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#sharein) is to use the `shareIn` operator:

```kotlin
val latestNews: Flow<List<ArticleHeadline>> = flow {
        ...
        // emit() here
}.shareIn(
    externalScope,
    replay = 1,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()
)
```

In my case, I want to emit only under specific conditions that are independent from the flow itself, so it is unpractical to `emit` inside the `flow{ ... }` body. As a consequence, I created a `MutableSharedFlow` and use `tryEmit` to emit whenever I need to, for example upon a method call:

```kotlin
// Backing property to avoid flow emissions from other classes
private val _tickFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(replay = 1, onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)
val tickFlow: SharedFlow<Int> = _tickFlow

// called after domain logic deciding which number to emit
fun timeToEmit(num:Int){
   _tickerFlow.tryEmit(num) 
}
```

What is the `SharingStarted` policy (if any) of a flow created through the `MutableSharedFlow<>()` constructor?
How can I set this flow `SharingStarted` property to be started (materialized) only when the number of subscribers is greater than 0?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it or an alternative?

Comment: Nope I ignored `SharingStarted` property in the end